# How to trigger activation event using Google Optimize in Angular js?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, single-page-application, analytics, google-optimize

We added Google Optimize snipe code at the header tag top of the page, also we added the et headTag

```html
<script>
  .async - hide {
    opacity: 0!important
  }
</script>

<script>
  (function(a, s, y, n, c, h, i, d, e) {
    s.className += ' ' + y;
    h.start = 1 * new Date;
    h.end = i = function() {
      s.className = s.className.replace(RegExp(' ?' + y), '')
    };
    (a[n] = a[n] || []).hide = h;
    setTimeout(function() {
      i();
      h.end = null
    }, c);
    h.timeout = c;
  })(window, document.documentElement, 'async-hide', 'dataLayer', 4000, {
    'GTM-XXXXX': true
  })
  ';
</script>

<<script>https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=UA-XXXXX</script>

  <script>
    window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];

    function gtag() {
      dataLayer.push(arguments);
    }
    gtag('js', new Date());
    gtag('config', 'UA-XXXXX ', {
      'optimize_id': 'GTM-XXXXC'
    });
  </script>
```

- after this Google Analytics snippet followed by GTM container script.
- When the application load at very 1st time, the variant changes visible after navigate from 1stpage to next page and coming back to page 1 changes are not retaining.
- can someone help me out how to trigger activation event on every page load?!